# Why are U.S. capital gains taxed at different rates?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

I am wondering, what is the purpose of dividing capital gains into long-term and short-term, and then tax them at different rates? Is it to incentivize long-term investments?

It seems counter-productive to tax short-term gains at the higher rate; if the tax rates were reversed, wouldn't it create incentive to realize gains more quickly, which would increase overall sales volume?

By the way, [this is the question I was really looking for](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/why-does-capital-gains-tax-apply-to-long-term-stock-holdings?rq=1) but it didn't show up in any of my searches until after I posted this.

Comment: Why a country's taxes are structured a particular way is more of a political question than a personal finance question. Perhaps you could get an answer at https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions?

Comment: What would be the supposed benefit of increased trading volume? It just makes the market a lot more volatile. Preferring short term gains would also reinforce the picture of the stock market as a giant casino

Comment: Capital gains are not specific to the stock market. My thinking was that increased volume (whether it be stock trading volume, real estate sales volume, etc.) generates business in the form of commissions and other fees (e.g. closing costs on a home purchase), and frees up cash that would otherwise be artificially tied up in assets for a longer period of time.

Comment: You are overlooking that transaction costs are lost money for investors. If I buy a home for 500 000€ and have 10% transaction cost (pretty normal here), sell the same home some time later for 700 000€ and have to pay 25% capital gains tax, I cannot buy an equal home somewhere else. I have just sent 100 000€ down the gutter (50k transaction cost, 50k tax). None of these make my home any better. The money is better invested in renovating the home, go to the bar and drink lots of beer, buy a new car, etc. All of which create jobs and actually increase the standard of living

Comment: Transaction costs are the same regardless of how long the asset is held. Consider an investor who flips houses by buying, renovating, and then selling. The cycle time for each investment may very well be less than a year, but the investor may decide to hold the property for a full year anyway in order to minimize taxes, if it results in a higher profit. This is not beneficial to anybody, as the house will likely sit vacant longer than it would if the investor sold it as soon as possible. In this case, the higher short-term gains tax is limiting the amount of business that can be done.

Answer (score 7):

The long-term capital gains tax rate is lower because it  encourages investment  in businesses.  This creates jobs and grows the economy.

Lower long term rates also encourages saving.

Comment: At least, that appears to be the thinking behind the different rates. I don't know whether it's supported by evidence.